# jQuery tabs need shifting

Tags: css

I am having trouble with aligning jQuery tags, I've used a bit of a code and changed it and styled it myself, however the align seems to be leaving a space on the left, which I don't want, and I'm not sure how to get rid of it. Here's what I mean...

http://postimage.org/image/8k5rcz941/

This is the CSS code:

```
.usual {
  color:#111;
  padding:15px 20px;
  margin:8px auto;
}
.usual li { list-style:none; float:left; }
.usual ul a {
  display:block;
  padding:6px 10px;
  text-decoration:none!important;
  margin:1px;
  margin-left:0;
  font:10pt Verdana;
  color:#FFF;
  background:#444;
}
.usual ul a:hover {
  color:#FFF;
  background:#111;
  }
.usual ul a.selected {
  margin-bottom:0;
  color:#fff;
  background:#003663;
  border-bottom:1px solid snow;
  cursor:default;
  }
.usual div {
  padding:10px 10px 8px 10px;
  *padding-top:3px;
  *margin-top:-15px;
  clear:left;
  background:snow;
  font:8pt Verdana;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}
.usual div a { color:#000; font-weight:bold; }
```

Hope you can help me shift this to the left, I've been trying to figure out what it is, and just can't :(

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Any chance you can show us a page with that code in it?  The screenshot is helpful, but a live demo would be much easier to diagnose.  If you can't, try inspecting the elements with FireBug and see where the space is getting added in and what rules are responsible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that the `ul` has a margin or padding applied. Remove it:

```css
.usual > ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.usual` has a left padding of 20px. Is that what you're trying to get rid of?

Answer (score 0):

Inspect your elements in either Google Chrome or using the Web Developer add-on for FireFox.  Find the element and check all it's inherited styles; chances are likely, like icktoofay says, you probably have inheritance somewhere.  If doing like he said, adding margin & padding = 0 for the UL, you can try the hack !important

```
.usual ul {
margin: 0 !important;
padding: 0 !important;
}
```

But note that if you have any other margin/padding that is used on the UL element, you will lose those, either using !important or not because `margin: 0` sets all 4 sides.  To target just the left side:

```
.usual ul {
margin-left: 0 !important;
padding-left: 0 !important;
}
```

Sometimes the hack won't work, that's why it's important to check your inheritance by inspecting the elements in the browser first.